# How to do color filtering/masking without HSV color space?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My team and I are wondering if it's possible to perform color filtering on an image using only RGB values. So far we've only found solutions for HSV. We're using Jupyter Notebook. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb


test = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
test = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(test) # result below
```

[image]

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

lower_orange = np.array([10, 100, 20]) # hsv color space
upper_orange = np.array([25, 255, 255]) # hsv color space
orange_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_orange, upper_orange)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(test, test, mask = orange_mask)
plt.imshow(res) # result below
```

[image]

So, the above code works, but we have to use HSV color space.

Here's code that I've tried with no HSV conversion (the range values are direct conversions of the original orange HSV used above to RGB):

```
lower_orange_rgb = np.array([20, 14, 12]) # rgb color space
upper_orange_rgb = np.array([255, 106, 0]) # rgb color space
orange_mask_rgb = cv2.inRange(test, lower_orange_rgb, upper_orange_rgb)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(test, test, mask = orange_mask_rgb)
plt.imshow(res) # result below
```

[image]

So, it's just blank, didn't work. Can we perform the same filter/mask with only RGB color space (no converting to HSV)? If so, how? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I suspect that `cv2.inRange` simply threshold each channel. In that regards, it is a lot easier to work in HSV: you want `H` to vary by little, and you don't care about `S` and `V`. Theoretically, since HSV is a linear trasformation of RGB, you can work in RGB as well, but the function will be a lot more complicated for the general color. Not to mention that, at the end of the day, the function would be similar to 1) transform to hsv, 2) thresholding on hsv; because that's intuitively what color filtering is.

Comment: It might be possible to do this directly in RGB, but what's your motivation?  If you think it would be faster, you might be wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom We don't necessarily want it to be faster. For our project, we're given specific RGB ranges to create a filter. Currently, we convert those into HSV to do our color filtering, but it was never accurate, and while the masks would sort of work, they weren't perfectly aligned with the proper range we were given. We were hoping to just skip this process.

Comment: Yes, you can use any color space

Comment: @Miki is there a link to some documentation or a tutorial that can do this? Or could you provide an answer as to how?

Comment: @jdizzle You do it in exactly the same way you do for the HSV colorspace, you just don't convert the image. If that's not giving you the results you desire, then you need to post a [mre] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @beaker edited the question a bunch that hopefully addresses a minimal reproducible example, thanks!

Comment: When you say *"no dice"*, I assume you are aware that the 30 in your `upper_orange` Hue corresponds to **60** in most online HSV converters....

Comment: Is 12 < 0?.....

Answer (score 0):

When you look at a vibrant image you see colors. OpenCV and Numpy don't. They see an array of numbers. This takes all the complexity out of color.

It's easy to find all the colors in an image by iterating through each row and column, and then saving the pixel value into a list:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np   
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/bIeGp.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (300,300))
colors = img[100:150,100:250].copy()

# Iterate through each pixel in the colors image
colorsList = []
for x in range(colors.shape[1]):
    for y in range(colors.shape[0]):
        colorsList.append(tuple(colors[y,x]))
```

The code above creates a list that contains all the pixel values for the colors in this image:

[image: match image]

Once you know those colors you can iterate though each pixel in the image and see if the color is contained on the list of colors:

```
for y in range(img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(img.shape[1]):
        #print(tuple(img[y,x]))
        if colorsList.count(tuple(img[y,x])) > 0:
            img[y,x] = 1,1,1
        else: img[y,x] = 123,123,123
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

@Miki pointed out my foolish mistake. Thank you. Thanks everyone for the comments and help. I'm getting a good mask now, although it's not identical to the HSV one. I have to make sure that each R, G, and B value for the lower range of the mask need to be less than its corresponding R, G, or B value for the upper range of the mask. I guess HSV to RGB conversion isn't as straightforward as it seems. Still confused about that, since I thought it was a linear conversion (could be a mistake of the online converter I was using, though).

Comment: You need to think of it as comparing each of R,G,B channels of the image *separately*, not as a single r,g,b color. The lower threshold of each channel must have a value less than that in the upper threshold.